# Python/Tweepy - ReadTimeoutError: Twitter Cursor API with more 200k followers

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, timeout, tweepy

I'm extracting the followers of a Twitter user, I use tweepy with Python 3.x. It goes very well with users who have less than 200k followers, on top of this, I have a timeout error.

```
consumer_key = '....'
consumer_secret  = '....'
access_token  = '....'
access_secret  = '....'

#twitter connection api
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)


user_ids = []

try:
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=twitter_account, count=5000).pages():
        user_ids.extend(page)

except tweepy.RateLimitError:
    logging.info ("RateLimitError...waiting 1000 seconds to continue")
    time.sleep(1000)
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=twitter_account, count=5000).pages():
        user_ids.extend(page)

following = []
```

The error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Try setting the API timeout, but I did not succeed.

```
api = tweepy.API(auth, timeout=200000, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
```

As set the option wait_on_rate_limit=True, in the log write five to six times:

```
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 8xx
```

Comment: You should sleep 60*1000 as the limit is 15 requests per minute : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-followers-ids.html

Comment: Never in the except.

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is :

- send 15 consecutive requests to get IDs pages
- wait for 8xx seconds because of rate limit
- then keep on gettings IDs, but you have been waiting for too long (8xx s), so you get a "read time out".

The right way should be, as you can send 15 requests within 15 minutes, to have a 1 minute break between each :

```
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=twitter_account, count=5000).pages():
    user_ids.extend(page)
    time.sleep(60000)
```